# Indeed API search for particular company

Tags: php, api

I am developing a job portal and using the [Indeed API](http://www.indeed.com/jsp/apiinfo.jsp).

In my request to the Indeed API I am using following parameters to search:

```
$params = array(
        "q" => $query,
        "co" => $country,
        "jt" => $jt,
        "salary" => $salary,
        "start" => $start,
        "limit" => $limit,
        "userip" => $ipaddress,
        "useragent" => $user_agent
    );

$results = $client->search($params);
```

Now I want to make a more specific search. For example, 
I want to search for particular company like Facebook, Microsoft etc
and want to add an advanced search feature "With these words in the title".

How can I add these two parameters to the search? These filters are not listed in the search parameters of the Indeed API specification.

Comment: Can I suggest you look at the indeed API manual

Comment: it is not properly provided, I have mentioned in detail, and that is why I am asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when we try to do advance serch in indeed, like for company "facebook" than on result page we get in search box some thing like "company:Facebook".

So using this format in q parameter we can search that and to add other parameter also simple add space and that parameter in advance search.

like for company and title it will be like this

```
q="company:facebook title:Executive Assistant"
```

This will work for advance search, don't use url parameter like as_cmp and all it is not working.

Answer (score 7):

FYI: indeed has discontinued their API.

I am posting this here because their website still lists it as active but when one tries to get a publisher id one gets redirected to an unrelated page without any explanation.  After some time I called indeed and they told me it was discontinued.

Hopefully this saves other people time from trying to figure out what they are doing wrong in trying to get a publisher id.

Comment: Did Indeed publish a Job Search API? Not sure which it is by looking at their API listings. Thank you.

Comment: @watts  If you are not seeing it now they have finally take down the documentation for their discontinued API.

Comment: Today, in early 2024, you can also find alternatives to the Indeed API on [RapidAPI](https://rapidapi.com/category/Jobs), [APIlist](https://apilist.fun/category/jobs), or [APIfy](https://apify.com/store/categories/jobs)

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, so posting here.  In case it is of use, here is the helpful reply I received from Indeed support.  Thank you Indeed!

Hello,

Thank you for your interest in Indeed.

You can utilize our Advanced Search to create a targeted q value for your API calls. You can do this here: http://www.indeed.com/advanced_search? Add your criteria, press search then add the q value located in the 'What" box to your API calls. Please note, the more targeted search the less results.

For example: Here, I entered the "with these words in the title" junior developer and "company" IBM and received 3 results:

http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=yourpublishernumber&q=title:(Junior%20Developer)%20company:IBM&l=&sort=&radius=&st=&jt=&start=&limit=&fromage=&filter=&latlong=1&co=us&chnl=&userip=1.2.3.4&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2

In this example, I used the selection "With all of these words" with junior developer and company "IBM" and received 28 results:

http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=yourpublishernumber&q=Junior%20Developer%20company:IBM&l=&sort=&radius=&st=&jt=&start=&limit=&fromage=&filter=&latlong=1&co=us&chnl=&userip=1.2.3.4&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2

Please give this a try and let me know if it doesn't meet your needs.

Thank you,
Indeed Support Team
Indeed - How the World Works.™